# How do i merge multiple views in SQL with one observation per record?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three views that i need to merge so i can only have one record per beneficiary ID. See the views below:
![Views][1]

1. Farmers View

   (Service_Farmer,Beneficiary_ID,Household_ID,FirstName,LastName,FullName,Sex
   ,Status)
2. Lead Farmers View

   (Service_Lead_Farmer,Household_ID,Beneficiary_ID,FirstName,LastName,Sex,Status)
3. SILC Members View

   (Service_SILC,Beneficiary_ID,Household_ID,FirstName,LastName,Sex)

How can i write a SQL Server code to merge these views so i can tell if someone is a farmer, lead farmer or silc member,etc?

Comment: Use join. Probably full outer.

Comment: Does a `Beneficiary_ID` only appear in one of the views, or might it appear in more than one? Is there another view or table that you're not showing that contains Beneficiary information?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have another table, `Beneficiaries` perhaps, something like the following:

```
select b.Beneficiary_ID, f.Service_Farmer, lf.Service_Lead_Farmer, sm.Service_SILC, other_columns_as_needed
from Beneficiaries b
left join Farmers f on b.Beneficiary_ID = f.BeneficiaryID
left join LeadFarmers lf on b.Beneficiary_ID = lf.Beneficiary_ID
left join SILCMembers sm on b.Beneficiary_ID = sm.Beneficiary_ID
where whatever_conditions_are_relevant
```